# Why does this assert throw a format exception when comparing structures?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, mstest, string-formatting

I'm trying to assert the equality of two `System.Drawing.Size` structures, and I'm getting a format exception instead of the expected assert failure.

```
[TestMethod]
public void AssertStructs()
{
    var struct1 = new Size(0, 0);
    var struct2 = new Size(1, 1);

    //This throws a format exception, "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format."
    Assert.AreEqual(struct1, struct2, "Failed. Expected {0}, actually it is {1}", struct1, struct2); 

    //This assert fails properly, "Failed. Expected {Width=0, Height=0}, actually it is {Width=1, Height=1}".
    Assert.AreEqual(struct1, struct2, "Failed. Expected " + struct1 + ", actually it is " + struct2); 
}
```

Is this intended behavior? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: have you tried having `Assert.AreEqual(struct1, struct2, string.Format("Failed expected {0} actually is {1}`, struct1.ToString(), struct2.ToString()))`?

Comment: That works fine; however I'm curious as to why Assert.AreEqual() can't format a string with structure types.

Comment: @Kyle Out of curiosity, this isn't with the Silverlight compatible version of the Unit Testing framework, is it? I can reproduce it with those DLLs (haven't tried the full .NET framework version yet) EDIT: nevermind, tested with the full ones too and still failed. :)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair nope, this is using whatever version of mstest that comes with Visual Studio 2010 ultimate. The test project itself is targeting .NET Framework 4

Comment: Not sure if you give a damn, but this works fine in NUnit. I have seen more "issues" like these in MStest. NUnit seems a bit more mature (to me at least). +1 for the post

Comment: Wow, I ran into this bug a few years ago... It's still not fixed? :(

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I've got it. And yes, it's a bug.

The problem is that there are two levels of `string.Format` going on here.

The *first* level of formatting is something like:

```
string template  = string.Format("Expected: {0}; Actual: {1}; Message: {2}",
                                 expected, actual, message);
```

Then we use `string.Format` with the parameters you've supplied:

```
string finalMessage = string.Format(template, parameters);
```

(Obviously there's cultures being provided, and *some* sort of sanitization... but not enough.)

That looks fine - unless the expected and actual values themselves end up with braces in, after being converted to a string - which they do for `Size`. For example, your first size ends up being converted to:

```
{Width=0, Height=0}
```

So the second level of formatting is something like:

```
string.Format("Expected: {Width=0, Height=0}; Actual: {Width=1, Height=1 }; " +
              "Message = Failed expected {0} actually is {1}", struct1, struct2);
```

... and that's what's failing. Ouch.

Indeed, we can prove this really easily by fooling the formatting to use our parameters for the expected and actual parts:

```
var x = "{0}";
var y = "{1}";
Assert.AreEqual<object>(x, y, "What a surprise!", "foo", "bar");
```

The result is:

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<foo>. Actual:<bar>. What a surprise!
```

Clearly broken, as we weren't expecting `foo` nor was the actual value `bar`!

Basically this is like a SQL injection attack, but in the rather less scary context of `string.Format`.

As a workaround, you can use `string.Format`as StriplingWarrior suggests. That avoids the second level of formatting being performed on the result of formatting with the actual/expected values.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Jon! I did end up using StriplingWarriors work around.

Comment: Has anyone submitted a bug report for this?

Comment: @Kevin: Yup - although internally, so I'm not sure whether progress will be publicly visible until it's fixed.

Comment: @Kevin I put one in to MS as well once it was confirmed a bug. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779528/assert-areequal-t-method-t-t-string-object-throws-a-format-exception-when-comparing-structures if you want to track it publicly.

Answer (score 43):

I think you've found a bug.

This works (throws an assert exception):

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
Assert.AreEqual(a, b, "Not equal {0} {1}", a, b);
```

And this works (outputs the message):

```
var a = new{c=1};
var b = new{c=2};
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Not equal {0} {1}", a, b));
```

But this doesn't work (throws a `FormatException`):

```
var a = new{c=1};
var b = new{c=2};
Assert.AreEqual(a, b, "Not equal {0} {1}", a, b);
```

I can't think of any reason this would be expected behavior. I'd submit a bug report. In the meantime, here's a workaround:

```
var a = new{c=1};
var b = new{c=2};
Assert.AreEqual(a, b, string.Format("Not equal {0} {1}", a, b));
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @StriplingWarrior that this does indeed appear to be a bug with the Assert.AreEqual() method on at least 2 overloads. As StiplingWarrior has already pointed out, the following fails;

```
var a = new { c = 1 };
var b = new { c = 2 };
Assert.AreEqual(a, b, "Not equal {0} {1}", a, b);
```

I've been doing a little experimenting on this further on being a little more explicit in code usage. The following doesn't work either;

```
// specify variable data type rather than "var"...no effect, still fails
Size a = new Size(0, 0);
Size b = new Size(1, 1);
Assert.AreEqual(a, b, "Not equal {0} {1}", a, b);
```

And

```
// specify variable data type and name the type on the generic overload of AreEqual()...no effect, still fails
Size a = new Size(0, 0);
Size b = new Size(1, 1);
Assert.AreEqual<Size>(a, b, "Not equal {0} {1}", a, b);
```

This got me thinking. System.Drawing.Size is a struct. What about objects? The param list *does* specify that the list after the `string` message is `params object[]`. Technically, yes structs *are* objects...but special *kinds* of objects, ie, value types. I think this is where the bug lies. If we use our own object with a similar usage and structure to `Size`, the following actually **does** work;

```
private class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int width, int height)
        : base()
    { Width = width; Height = height; }

    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var test1 = new MyClass(0, 0);
    var test2 = new MyClass(1, 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(test1, test2, "Show me A [{0}] and B [{1}]", test1, test2);
}
```

Comment: The problem is not whether it is `class` or `struct`, but whether the `ToString` value contains curly brackets that look like a `String.Format`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the first assert is  incorrect.

Use this instead:

```
Assert.AreEqual(struct1, 
                struct2, 
                string.Format("Failed expected {0} actually is {1}", struct1, struct2));
```

Comment: According to the documentation I should be able to call AreEqual with a formatted string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx , specifically parameters
    Type: System.Object[]
    An array of parameters to use when formatting message.